# Custom Log classes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am trying to create custom Log classes in my application which use the default channel but write in a different file, but i can't find any relevant documentation for my needs.

Use case :

In UserService i want to call `UserLogger::info('info');` which will write in user_log.php

In CarService i want to call `CarLogger::info('info');` which will write in car_log.php

Currently i have an abstract class which has function :

```
protected static function setUpLogger(): \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
{
    return Log::build([
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path(static::$path),
    ]);
}
```

I am using it each time i'm calling custom loggers, but it's probably a very bad approach.

**Does anyone have an idea on how i can achieve custom log classes in described way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add own channels, by editing `config/logging.php`:

```
'user' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path'   => storage_path('logs/user_log.php'),
    'level'  => 'debug',
],
```

Then you can create logger using your new channel:

```php
class UserLogger
{
    public static function info($message, $context = []): void
    {
        Log::channel('user')->info($message, $context);
    }

    ...
}
```

and now you can use `CarLogger::info('info');`.

The same steps fro `CarLogger` or any other separate loggers and you should be good to go.

Comment: As mentionned in question, i would like to keep same channel, just change the filename i'm writing in

Comment: Well, that sounds like you want to have channels without using channels :)

Comment: So there is no way i can simply change writing file in default channel dynamically? It just seems weird i need to create a channel for each simple filename

Comment: This is how it is designed. You can call this a limitation but this is how it works. If that's not acceptable, you need to look for different logger or try to extend Laravel's one. But I'd probably re-think the requirement first.